# How print a number and string on the same line with MARS/SPIM system calls?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Recently, I was doing my homework and was struggling to print variable and string on same line. I want to ask on how to print them on the same line in MIPS?

My current result:

```
Please enter your nickname: Harry
Please enter your surname: Chan
Harry
Chan
How old are you? 20
You are 20
 years old.
```

What I want:

```
Please enter your nickname: Harry
Please enter your surname: Chan
Harry
Chan
How old are you? 20
You are 20 years old.
```

MIPS code:

```
.data

question1: .asciiz "Please enter your nickname: "
question2: .asciiz "Please enter your surname: "
question3: .asciiz "How old are you? "
buffer1: .space 60
buffer2: .space 60
buffer3: .space 60
str1: .asciiz "You are "
str2: .asciiz " years old."

#-----Text Segment----------------- 
.text
.globl __start 
__start:
# ---------------------- 
# Write your code here
li $v0, 4
la $a0, question1
syscall

li $v0,8 #take in input
la $a0, buffer1 #load byte space into address
li $a1, 60 # allot the byte space for string
move $t0,$a0 #save string to t0
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, question2
syscall

li $v0,8 #take in input
la $a0, buffer2 #load byte space into address
li $a1, 60 # allot the byte space for string
move $t1,$a0 #save string to t1
syscall

la $a0, buffer1 #reload byte space to primary address
move $a0,$t0 # primary address = t0 address (load pointer)
li $v0,4 # print string
syscall

la $a0, buffer2 #reload byte space to primary address
move $a0,$t1 # primary address = t1 address (load pointer)
li $v0,4 # print string
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, question3
syscall

li $v0,8 #take in input
la $a0, buffer2 #load byte space into address
li $a1, 60 # allot the byte space for string
move $t2,$a0 #save string to t2
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, str1
syscall

la $a0, buffer1 #reload byte space to primary address
move $a0,$t2 # primary address = t2 address (load pointer)
li $v0,4 # print string
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, str2
syscall

# ----------------------
# Terminate the program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with the MIPS ISA, everything to do with the system calls that MARS/SPIM provide.  If the print-number system calls always append a newline, you'll need to convert the number to a string yourself.  (Or just read it as a string in the first place so you already have 2 strings that you can put together for one call to the output string syscall.)

Comment: Can you show me how to change the code?

Comment: Don't delete and re-post your comment to send a new notification, spamming is very rude!  You can google yourself for how to manually convert integer to string; there have been some SO questions about that for MIPS.

Comment: The first hit for a google search on `site:stackoverflow.com mips integer to string` is [Convert an int to a string of characters](//stackoverflow.com/q/20531292).  It actually does mix print-integer with print-string without getting extra newlines (to print single digits).  What MIPS simulator are you using?

Comment: I am using MARS for assembly language. Also, I am always using string and not knowing what do you mean about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from my classmate:

```
    #print out question 3 and store input

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, question3 

        syscall

        li $v0, 5
        syscall

        move $t0, $v0

    #print out str 1, str2 and answer

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, str1
        syscall

        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t0
        syscall

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, str2
        syscall
```